# Using token_replace in php filter with webform2pdf

Tags: 7, tokens

I'm trying to use submission id of webform in webform2pdf.

My problem it is possibility of usage result of token_replace in php filter.

```
<?php
  $node = node_load(53470);
  $sid_token = '[submission:sid]';
  $sid = token_replace($sid_token, array('node' => $node));
  print 'strlen($sid) = '. strlen($sid);
  foreach (str_split($sid) as $position => $symbol) {
    print 'Position ' . $position . ', symbol ' . $symbol . '<br>';
  }
  print 'echo($sid) = '; echo($sid);
?>
```

[submission:sid] must return string '145', but result is:

```
strlen($sid) = 16

Position 0, symbol [
Position 1, symbol s
Position 2, symbol u
Position 3, symbol b
Position 4, symbol m
Position 5, symbol i
Position 6, symbol s
Position 7, symbol s
Position 8, symbol i
Position 9, symbol o
Position 10, symbol n
Position 11, symbol :
Position 12, symbol s
Position 13, symbol i
Position 14, symbol d
Position 15, symbol ]

echo($sid) = 145
```

As I understand it means that token_replace function is called after php filtered expression execution but I need to use result of $sid inside php

```
<?php $submission = webform_get_submission(53470, $sid); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use [`token_replace()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7.x), you need to provide it with a proper data array. Since you provide it with a node, your token replace can only replace `[node:*]` tokens (exceptions for global tokens such as `[site:*]`). If your submission is a node, you should be able to use `[node:nid]` instead.

If you were to use `$sid = token_replace($sid_token, array('submission' => $node));`, you can use tokens like `[submission:*]`, but only with node properties (`nid` instead of `sid`).

If your submission is of another entity type, you will have to provide that as data as well.

Comment: Does it means that submission is global token for my use case if `$sid = token_replace($sid_token); print $sid;` prints `145` ? Maybe you can explain me how i should get correct data array to use submission tokens?

Comment: Ah, it seems I misunderstood the problem. What is the value of `$node->sid`?

Comment: Thank you for you help! `$node->sid` is not exists.

Comment: Here is result of `var_dump($node);`: https://pastebin.com/ggFts2UL

Comment: I do not have that much experience with webform, but you paste confirms what I thought. Node 53470 is the webform node (I initially though that was the submission). This basically means that your code is not yet aware of the available submissions. But you should be able to retrieve an array of submissions for this webform node by using [webform_get_submissions](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_get_submissions/7): `$submissions = webform_get_submissions(('nid' => 53470));`

Comment: Yes, you are right: `$submissions = webform_get_submissions(array('nid' => 53470));` gives the array of submissions and 145 is one of them. But I'sorry, I still do not understand how can i select correct **sid** from $submissions array. I've being suppose that using token [submission:sid] or [webform:sid] gives me nedded sid.

Comment: If you have the array of submissions, you no longer need to use the token. (Tokens are really for the front-end (rendering, forms, etc), if you work in the back-end there are other solutions). You also no longer need the `sid` for `webform_get_submission`, because `webform_get_submissions` already already loaded all submissions.

Comment: I do not understand what problem you want to solve here. You want to load the submission based on the sid. But from my understanding you already have access to the submission token. So there should be no need to load it. You can access all submitted values with `[submission:values:?]`. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2790291

Comment: I can access to [submission:values:?] outsite of <?php ?> for filling template of pdf, but I want to load other node's field using php filter, the `nid` of this node is stored in field `source_nid` of webform submission. Now i will try to use `$submissions` array and I've only need to get `sid` for use correct submission. Thank you again!

Comment: If source_nid is an entity reference field, you might be able to chain it like this: `[submission:values:source_nid:FIELD_NAME]`. It seems I really do not know enough about this. Good luck.

Comment: No really, you should not accept if I did not answer your question. I'll delete it and someone else (or yourself) can write an answer that does answer the question. :)

Comment: By marking it as accepted, your chances of getting an answer by somebody else are much smaller.

Comment: Ok. I think what you answer is the best now =) . And with your help I've moved forward a lot.

Comment: Then give me an upvote for the effort instead, it is not a complete answer to the question :)

Comment: Ok, I will give back my acception until I've decide my problem completely.